# How to test non-negativity of linear functions on homogeneous semi-algebraic sets?

Tags: optimization, real-algebraic-geometry

Fix a homogeneous semi-algebraic set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, by which I mean that the set $S$ is defined by inequalities $f_{1},...,f_{k} \geq 0$, where $f_{1},...,f_{k}$ are homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Given linear functions $g_{1},...,g_{l}$, I'd like to test if they are non-negative on $S$.

Is this possible in principle? Is there an algorithm with a name for doing this? Is there software for checking this?

EDIT: Is it possible to determine if the linear functions $g_{1},...,g_{l}$ are positive when $S$ is the space of semi-positive definite matrices subject to a linear constraint on the entries?

Answer (score 0):

Semidefinite Programming is an efficient way of optimizing linear functions over the set of positive semi-definite matrices subject to a linear constraint on the entries. So the answer to your Edit is yes. There are for example packages for Matlab.

Using some ideas from Real Algebraic Geometry, your original problem can be reduced to a hierachy of semidefinite programs, so the answer is again yes. The keyword is "Lasserre's Relaxation".